# Отображение формата Decimal в целом виде asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Такой вопрос, у меня есть БД и цена хранится в decimal.

Как отображать цену из БД не в таком формате 123,00, а в таком 123.

Из базы выводится вот так

```
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)
```

Просто перевести в стринг и добавить параметр "{0:0.##}" не выходит, не знаю как правильно это сделать в asp.net

Comment: `Math.Truncate()` вернет целую часть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен,

```
   1) @Math.Truncate(Model.Price)либо так;

   2) @String.Format("{0:0.##}", Model.Price) либо так;
```